# Countdown reset automatically after input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've used Countdown and ReactCodeInput on my project and it works.
But when I combined it with simple input, it restarts whenever my input changes.
I want to restart it only and only if time over. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown-now";
import ReactCodeInput from "react-code-input";
const lengthToken = 6;

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
      secondsToExpire: 600000
    };
  }

  saveTokenToState = token => {
    this.setState({ token });
  };

  render() {
    const renderer = ({ minutes, seconds }) => (
      <span>
        {minutes}:{seconds}
      </span>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="token">
          <ReactCodeInput
            inputmode="numeric"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
            type="number"
            name="test"
            fields={lengthToken}
            value={this.state.token}
            onChange={this.saveTokenToState}
            inputStyle={codeStyle}
          />
        </label>
        <Countdown
          renderer={renderer}
          date={Date.now() + this.state.secondsToExpire}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the *expiration date* in your component's state, instead of the delay, re-rendering your component would not trigger a recomputation of `Date.now() + secondsToExpire` in the `Countdown` child :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let date = Date.now() + delay;
    this.state = {
        token: "",
        expirationDate: date
    };
}

...
return <div>
    ...
    <Countdown date={this.state.expirationDate} ...>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using setState in the onChange handler, which will cause a re-render. This is why your Countdown resets. I imagine one way to handle this is to put Countdown in a separate class and extend React.PureComponent to let it handle the update for you. Alternatively write your own [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in that class, although this is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this changes:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown-now";
import ReactCodeInput from "react-code-input";
const lengthToken = 6;

class Test extends Component {
  countdownDate;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
      secondsToExpire: 600000
    };
    this.countdownDate = Date.now() + this.state.secondsToExpire;
  }

  saveTokenToState = token => {
    this.setState({ token });
  };

  render() {
    const renderer = ({ minutes, seconds }) => (
      <span>
        {minutes}:{seconds}
      </span>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="token">
          <ReactCodeInput
            inputmode="numeric"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
            type="number"
            name="test"
            fields={lengthToken}
            value={this.state.token}
            onChange={this.saveTokenToState}
          />
        </label>
        <Countdown renderer={renderer} date={this.countdownDate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```